# Customize log provider list for just one class

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

My application has a log factory with two providers: one of them writes to a file and the other makes a REST call to save on a vendor repository. I use loggerFactory to create a logger on almost every class class and this includes my Rest client factory that I use for all rest calls.

```
//Creates Rest Clients
public class RestClientFactory
{
    public RestClient Create(string name)
    {  
    return new RestClient(this.customLoggerFactory.Create(name));
    }
}

//Custom Rest client
public class RestClient{
    private readonly ICustomLoggerFactory logger;

    public RestClient(ICustomLoggerFactory logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Response Execute(Request req)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("Start")
            // Web Client logic
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // This is where the problem is. Assuming the Vendor Rest 
            // Client is failing, the code will loop into this section
            logger.Error("Something went wrong", ex);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomLoggerFactory:ICustomLoggerFactory {
    private ILoggerFactory msLogger; //MS framework logger factory

    public CustomLoggerFactory(ILoggerFactory msLogger){
        this.mslogger = mslogger;
    }    

    CustomLogger Create(string name){
        this.loggerFactory.CreateLogger(name);
    }
}


public class CustomLogger{
    public void Debug(string message){
        // Debug logging logic
    }
     public void Error(string message, Exception ex){
         // Error logging logic
     }
}
```

This creates a loop where if I get an error AND if the vendor site is down, this happens:

1. Error happens and calls Rest Log provider Rest call is attempted.
2. It fails(assume vendor is down)
3. The error call triggers another call to Rest log provider
4. Back to step 3
   .... and so on

Is there a way to toggle the provider in between? Something that say if( restClient is VendorRestClient), ignore Rest Api log provider? I'm trying to make sure any error by the provider doesn't make another log call to the same provider.

Comment: Instead of using a factory, why not use dependency injection?  You could scope the implementations in your IOC config

Comment: [ILoggerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory) only defines a method named *CreateLogger* but no *Create*. Do you use the built-in logging framework (*Microsoft.Extensions.Logging*)? Could you show us some more code, e.g. how is the Rest log provider implemented?

Comment: @maccettura, even with IOC, the logger component would be built with the same loggerFactory at eventually right?

Comment: @AdamSimon, I made an error while attempting to short hand the code. What I have is a custom logger factory that internally calls the MS loggerFactory.Create to create the logger object. Also, the rest log provider is a vendor code and cannot be changed.

Comment: Please fix the code in your post as it's not valid C#. Furthermore, I'd need some more info to be able to come up with a solution. Do I understand correctly that the Rest log provider (which is a 3rd party component) uses your rest client implementation to store log messages on a remote server? How does step 3 happen exactly? Is this an endless recursion when logging an error like `logger.LogError(ex, "Error");`? Or is there some global exception handler which catches the exception thrown by the Rest client when it fails and tries to log this exception causing the endless loop?

Comment: @AdamSimon, I updated the code. Hope it helps. Let me answer your questions in order. Yes, the Rest log provider uses a rest client implementation to store log messages. Step 3 would happen if the vendor rest api is throwing an error. Assuming an error happened somewhere, the log provider will attempt to make a rest call. Assuming the vendor endpoint was down, it will attempt to do a log.error which will again try to do step 3 and so on. The endless recursion is exactly due to logger.Error("Something went wrong", ex);